# Deleting mutliple rows with ExecuteMany Oracledb Node-Oracledb

Tags: node.js, express, node-oracledb

please, I can't find where the problem is.

I followed exactly the same method as the GitHub examples, but it still doesn't work.

There are no incidents, but every time, it's 0 rowAffected.

The problem is in relation to the delete, with the insert it works fine.

code:

```
data =[
  [ 'khaled', 'Paris' ],
  [ 'ivan', 'Madrid' ]
 ];

const sql = 'DELETE FROM USERS WHERE u_name= :1 and u_town = :2'

const res1 = await connection.executeMany(sql,data,{autoCommit:true});

console.log(res1) ==> rowAffected=0
```

and when I try it on an oracle client, it works, the data exists.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Check you are connecting to the same database & user in Node.js and the 'oracle client' (whatever that is).

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that the rows are actually not getting deleted? They might be, and you're just seeing 0 in the rowsAffected? If so, you could try setting the dmlRowCounts option to see the result count, [per this documentation](http://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#identifying-affected-rows-with-executemany)

```
data =[
  [ 'khaled', 'Paris' ],
  [ 'ivan', 'Madrid' ]
 ];
const options = {autoCommit:true, dmlRowCounts: true, batchErrors: true}
const sql = 'DELETE FROM USERS WHERE u_name= :1 and u_town = :2'

const res1 = await connection.executeMany(sql,data,options);

console.log(res1) ==> rowAffected=0
console.log(res1.dmlRowCounts);
console.log(res1.batchErrors);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes i did, and the rows  still not deleting :(

Comment: Can you try with the extra changes above and post the output? Also, which github example are you basing this on? Can you add the link to that?

Comment: The executeMany examples are the em_* files in https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/main/examples

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.  For example:

```
/*

drop table users;
create table users (u_name varchar2(20), u_town varchar2(20));
insert into users values ( 'khaled', 'Paris' );
insert into users values ( 'ivan', 'Madrid' );
commit;
select * from users;

*/

const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const dbConfig = require('./dbconfig.js');

if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
  oracledb.initOracleClient({libDir: process.env.HOME + '/Downloads/instantclient_19_8'});
}

async function run() {
  let connection;

  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);

    const res = await connection.execute(`select * from users`);
    console.log(res.rows);  // [ [ 'khaled', 'Paris' ], [ 'ivan', 'Madrid' ] ]
    
    const data =[
      [ 'khaled', 'Paris' ],
      [ 'ivan', 'Madrid' ]
    ];
    const options = {autoCommit:true, dmlRowCounts: true, batchErrors: true};
    const sql = 'DELETE FROM USERS WHERE u_name= :1 and u_town = :2';

    const res1 = await connection.executeMany(sql,data,options);
    console.log(res1);  // { rowsAffected: 2, dmlRowCounts: [ 1, 1 ] }
    

    const res2 = await connection.execute(`select * from users`);
    console.log(res2.rows);  // []
    
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
    await connection.close();
      } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

run();
```

Output is:

```
[ [ 'khaled', 'Paris' ], [ 'ivan', 'Madrid' ] ]
{ rowsAffected: 2, dmlRowCounts: [ 1, 1 ] }
[]
```

And in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> select * from users;

no rows selected
```